# Stop loop iteration based on user input

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to make a simple program that calculates distance traveled based on user entered speed, and time. It outputs each distance traveled for each hour and outputs that to a list box. I am not sure how to make the loop stop iterating at the user entered time. I am also not sure if the for loop is the proper loop to use.

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //decalre variables for speed, time, distance 
        double speed;
        double time;
        double distance;

        //declare constants to be used
        const int interval = 1;
        const int start_hours = 0;
        const int end_hours = 10;


        if (double.TryParse(speedTextBox.Text, out speed))
        {

            //try to get time from hours text box
            if (double.TryParse(hoursTextBox.Text, out time))
            {

                //display table of speeds
                for (time = start_hours; time <= end_hours; time += interval)
                {
                    //calculate distance driven 
                    distance = speed * time;

                    //display the distance driven in an amount of time
                    listBox1.Items.Add("After " + time + " hours, the distance traveled is " + distance);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //invalid entry for hours
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry for time");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //invalid entry for speed
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter MPH");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: you already stop the for loop at the end hours: *time <= end_hours;*

Comment: I know, I set end_hours to be 10 as a fix/hack for the meantime. I need it to stop iterating due to the number of user entered hours. So if the user enters 3 hours, it determines the distance after 1 hour, then 2 hours, then 3 hours, and then stops iterating.

Comment: 1-don't declare end_hours as a const, justa plain int, 2-parse the text where the user enters the number and set it on end_hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

time needs to be the limit in the for loop.

```
  for (int i = start_hours; i <= time; i += interval)
            {
                //calculate distance driven 
                distance = speed * i;

                //display the distance driven in an amount of time
                listBox1.Items.Add("After " + i + " hours, the distance traveled is " + distance);
            }
```

Comment: Would I also change the output to the list box, putting the int "i" where time is?

 //display the distance driven in an amount of time
                listBox1.Items.Add("After " + i + " hours, the distance traveled is " + distance);

Comment: If you want to display every hour until the entered hour is reach in the for loop, then you will replace time with i. Time will show the entered hours, i will show hou

Comment: if you only wants to add to the listbox one time, you need to put the listbox1.items.add statement outside the for loop